# How can I "use" the controller in this program?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller

How can I connect the controller to the view in this application? I'm trying to create a simple snake game in Swing, using the MVC pattern.

I think I got the movement logic correct, but I don't understand how I can use the controller? I want the arrow keys to correspond to directions, so if I press the "up" key, I want the controller to send this to the model (Snake), which will in turn send this to the view (MainFrame).

I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing this.

```
public class GameLoop {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
                Snake snake = new Snake(mainFrame);
                Controller controller = new Controller(snake);
            }

        });
    }

}


public class Controller {



private List<ControllerListener> listeners;

    public Controller(ControllerListener... listeners) {
        this.listeners = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(listeners));
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        Direction dir = null;
        switch( keyCode ) { 
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                dir = Direction.NORTH;
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                dir = Direction.SOUTH;
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                dir = Direction.WEST;
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
                dir = Direction.EAST;
                break;
        }

        for(ControllerListener listener: listeners) {
            listener.controllerUsed(dir);
        }
    } 


}


public interface ControllerListener {

    void controllerUsed(Direction dir);

    }

    public enum Direction {
    WEST, NORTH, EAST, SOUTH;

    }


    public class MainFrame implements SnakeListener {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
    private List<Integer[]> snakeParts = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

    public MainFrame() {


        frame.add(drawPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    private class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for(Integer[] part : snakeParts) {
                g.fillOval(part[0], part[1], 10, 10);
            }


        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 600);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void snakeMoved(List<Integer[]> snakeParts) {
        this.snakeParts = snakeParts;
        drawPanel.repaint();
    }
}


public interface SnakeListener {

void snakeMoved(List<Integer[]> snakeParts);

}


public class Snake implements ControllerListener {

    private int headX, headY;
    private Direction direction;
    private List<Integer[]> snakeParts = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<SnakeListener> snakeListeners;

    public Snake(SnakeListener... listeners) {
        snakeListeners = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(listeners));

        headX = 10;
        headY = 10;
        direction = Direction.EAST;

        Integer[] part = new Integer[2];
        part[0] = headX;
        part[1] = headY;
        snakeParts.add(part);
    }

    public void move(Direction dir) {
        direction = dir;
        Integer[] part = {headX, headY};
        switch(dir) {
        case EAST:
            headX++;
            part[0] = headX;
            break;

        case NORTH:
            headY--;
            part[1] = headY;
            break;

        case SOUTH:
            headY++;
            part[1] = headY;
            break;

        case WEST:
            headX--;
            part[0] = headX;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        snakeParts.add(part);
        snakeParts.remove(0);

        for(SnakeListener listener : snakeListeners) {
            listener.snakeMoved(snakeParts);
        }
    }

    private void checkDefeat() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void controllerUsed(Direction dir) {
        move(dir);
    }

}
```

Comment: Here's one way to organize a [Retro Snake](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=768) game.